# Cannot read image file in appcelerator titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I have an image stored at /assets in my project folder and I am trying to read it using Ti.Filesystem.getFile(). The code prints the blob data in android but it prints **undefined** in iOS.
Following function is called on Button click event https://pastebin.com/QgqLQPyz

```
function readImg(e) {
var localPath = '/butterfly.jpg';
var cachedFilename = Ti.Utils.sha1(localPath) + localPath.substr(localPath.lastIndexOf('.'));
console.log("cachedFilename:---"+cachedFilename);
var cachedFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationCacheDirectory, cachedFilename);

if(!cachedFile.exists()){
    var blob = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, localPath).read();
    console.log("-----------blob in not exists:"+JSON.stringify(blob));
}
```

}

When the same image path is set in ImageView it gets displayed so the issue is not with path . What am I missing here ? pls help. Thank you.

Comment: This is because of app thinning, assets are put into an asset catalogue. Why do you need to read images like this if I may ask?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to read image width and height from blob data and resize it accordingly using "blob.imageAsCropped" to fit in my imageview .

Answer (score 1):

The best option so you don't have to do anything specific to the images at all (keep in mind, image manipulation is pretty heavy to do on runtime), is to use a module that was made for this purpose, [av.imageview](https://github.com/AndreaVitale/av.imageview). This allows you to configure all kinds of content modes.

An option to get your code to work is to get the blob using the the [`getAsset` method](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem-method-getAsset).

```
var blob = Ti.Filesystem.getAsset('/images/butterfly.jpg');
```

and then resize where you see fit. But I would advise you, if you do need to do this every time the app runs, then just resize once and store that resized image to be used after that. That way there will only be a single time the image needs resizing.

Comment: I tried var blob = Ti.Filesystem.getAsset('/images/butterfly.jpg'); but blob value is null. My image is located in app/assets/images/butterfly.jpg. And the idea is to resize the image only 1st time and stored it into applicationCacheDirectory which is referred as "cachedFile" in above code.

Comment: This works. From the docs: *This method is only applicable on images in assets catalogs for apps with app-thinning enabled on iOS. Since the bundled image has been reallocated into assets catalog, it is no longer accessible via the original file path. To obtain a Blob object representing this image, use the original file path as the parameter in this method instead of using it in getFile*